# Como utilizar ViewModel no MVC 5 C# com Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Estou tentando aprender como utilizar o conceito de ViewModel, por isso fiz um projeto básico, mas estou tendo dificuldades.

Tenho os seguintes Models:

- Pessoa

  - id
  - tipo
  - documento
- Fisica

  - id
  - nome
  - sobrenome
  - documento
- Juridica

  - id
  - razao_social
  - nome_fantasia
  - documento

A ideia do exemplo é informar no campo tipo do Model Pessoa se é F (Pessoa Fisica) ou J (Pessoa Juridica) e o campo documento, receberia o CNPJ ou CPF da Pessoa Fisica/Juridica.

Depois, os Models Juridica ou Fisica seriam preenchidos pelos dados específicos de cada tipo, mas o campo documento receberia o ID do seu respectivo CPF ou CNPJ.

Fiz esse relacionamento no banco de dados e importei para o meu projeto utilizando o ADO.Net Entity Data Model através da opção Code First from database.

Meus Models ficaram assim:

**(Tabela da Pessoa Fisica)**

```
[Table("Fisica")]
public partial class Fisica
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string sobrenome { get; set; }

    public int documento { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

**(Tabela da Pessoa Juridica)**

```
[Table("Juridica")]
public partial class Juridica
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string razao_social { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }

    public int documento { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

**(Tabela dos Documentos CPF ou CNPJ)**

```
[Table("Pessoa")]
public partial class Pessoa
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Pessoa()
    {
        Fisica = new HashSet<Fisica>();
        Juridica = new HashSet<Juridica>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string tipo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string documento { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Fisica> Fisica { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Juridica> Juridica { get; set; }
}
```

Em seguida, criei meu ViewModel da seguinte maneira:

**(ViewModel que contemple as 3 tabelas)**

```
public class ViewModelPessoas
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Fisica Fisica { get; set; }
    public Juridica Juridica { get; set; }
}
```

Não sei se até aí está correto ou se já tem algum erro, caso tenham, por favor, me apontem.

Minha ideia é criar uma view apenas onde, através de Javascript, se o usuário selecionar que irá cadastrar uma Pessoa Física, só irão aparecer os campos referentes a este tipo, acontecendo o contrário quando ele selecionar que irá cadastrar uma Pessoa Jurídica. Isso sei fazer, mas minha dificuldade agora estão sendo duas maiores:

1. Nesse modelo, eu consigo ainda utilizar o ModelState.IsValid para validar o Post do Formulário? Pois se ele só enviar dados da Pessoa Física, os campos de Pessoa Jurídica ficarão null, retornado que o ModelState.IsValide é false. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer essa validação?
2. Como faço para, dentro de uma única action, no caso a ActionResult Create(ViewModelPessoas modelo), eu cadastrar primeiramente na tabela Pessoa, obter o id auto-incremento gerado para esse documento cadastro e poder utilizá-lo em seguida quando for salvar os dados específicos da pessoa Física ou Jurídica (campo documento)?

Obrigado!

***~Adicionado em 04/09/2017:***

Consegui resolver verificando se o cadastro que está sendo enviado é do tipo PF ou PJ, se for PF então eu limpo os erros do campo PJ e vice-versa.

Consideram essa uma boa solução? Obrigado.

```
//Validar modelo
switch (modelo.Pessoa.tipo)
{
 case "F":
     ModelState["Juridica.razao_social"].Errors.Clear();
     ModelState["Juridica.nome_fantasia"].Errors.Clear();
     break;

 case "J":
     ModelState["Fisica.nome"].Errors.Clear();
     ModelState["Fisica.sobrenome"].Errors.Clear();
     break;

 default:
     ModelState.AddModelError("Pessoa.tipo", "Informe se o cadastro é Pessoa Física ou Pessoa Jurídica.");
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nesse modelo, eu consigo ainda utilizar o ModelState.IsValid para
>   validar o Post do Formulário? Pois se ele só enviar dados da Pessoa
>   Física, os campos de Pessoa Jurídica ficarão null, retornado que o
>   ModelState.IsValide é false. Qual a melhor maneira de fazer essa
>   validação?

Consegue. E validar `[Required]` ou pessoa física ou pessoa jurídica não conheço `DataAnnotations` para isso, você vai precisar fazer uma implementação própria e herdar de ValidationAttribute para isso, ou fazer essa validação em outro local.

> Como faço para, dentro de uma única action, no caso a ActionResult
>   Create(ViewModelPessoas modelo), eu cadastrar primeiramente na tabela
>   Pessoa, obter o id auto-incremento gerado para esse documento cadastro
>   e poder utilizá-lo em seguida quando for salvar os dados específicos
>   da pessoa Física ou Jurídica (campo documento)?

Isso é um mapeamento Joined (A chave primária de Pessoa é chave primária e estrangeira de Física/Jurídica)? Se for e você configurou corretamente o banco uma inserção só será suficiente, não é necessário retornar o id.

Mesmo assim, se quiser o retorno o id e você utiliza o entity ficaria assim:

```
Contexto.Pessoa.Add(entidade);
Contexto.SaveChanges();
//após o SaveChanges, a propriedade Id do seu objeto vai possuir o valor da chave.
var idGerado = entidade.Id;
return idGerado;
```

Comment: nessa linha
 Contexto.Pessoa.AddObject(entidade);
Você quis dizer isso:
 Contexto.Pessoa.Add(entidade);
Correto? Pois não encontrei esse método AddObject

Comment: Exato, vou corrigir

Comment: Em relação a salvar o id automaticamente nas tabelas sem eu precisar me preocupar em capturá-lo, realmente funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Sobre usar o ValidationAttribute para validação, ainda estou em dúvidas. Sei que consigo com ele adicionar validações personalizadas ao meu model, mas eu teria que, além disso, ignorar a validação da Pessoa Física ou então da Pessoa Jurídica dinamicamente, essa está sendo a maior dúvida. Mas até aqui já me ajudou bastante, obrigado.

Comment: A única validação que vai atrapalhar seria o `[Required]` e qualquer coisa que limite um valor mínimo, tudo isso tem que ser feita dentro de um ValidationAttribute. Normalmente, nesses casos de um ou outro não usa o `[Required]`